# Mechanics Fortran Preprocessor

Tags: scope, fortran, preprocessor, include-guards

I recently happened to come across the preprocessing option most Fortran compilers support these days (as explained e.g. in the [Fortran Wiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Preprocessors)) . Coming from a C background, I would like to better understand the mechanics and caveats related to the (Fortran-)preprocessor's `#include` directive.

To avoid any confusion right from the beginning: there are two `include` directives in Fortran (see e.g. [F77 reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vna1/index.html))

- `include "foo"` is a compiler directive, i.e. foo can only contain Fortran statements
- `#include "bar"` is a preprocessor directive, i.e. bar can contain `#defines` and the like

I am aware of this difference and I am interested in the second case only (my question is therefore not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498562/includes-revealing-with-fortran-preprocessor)).

I'll explain my questions using an example: assume we have two files, a header file (macro.h) and a source file (display.F):

**macro.h**

```
#define MSG() say_hello()
```

**display.F**

```
#include "macro.h"

    PROGRAM display
    CALL MSG()
    CALL another_message()
    END

    SUBROUTINE say_hello()
    WRITE(*,*) 'Hello.'
    END

    SUBROUTINE another_message()
    CALL MSG()
    END
```

Here are my questions:

**Scope**

where (globally, locally in the `SUBROUTINE` etc.) is the macro `MSG()` defined if I include macro.h:

1. at the beginning of the file (as above)?
2. at the beginning of the `PROGRAM display` (and nowhere else)?
3. at the beginning of e.g. `SUBROUTINE another_message()` (and nowhere else)?

From testing it seems: 1. globally, 2. in `PROGRAM` and all `SUBROUTINES`, 3. in that `SUBROUTINE` only. A confirmation of these assumptions and some theoretical explanations why would be great.

What of above (1. - 3.) is best practice for preprocessor includes?

**Include Guards**

If I have a multi-file project and I include header.h in multiple *.F source files, do I need to provide include guards?

In case the answers to the above questions should be compiler dependent (as preprocessing is not Fortran standard), I'd be most interested in ifort's behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules are the same as for the C preprocessor you know. GCC even uses the same `cpp` for C and Fortran (for Fortran in the traditional mode). Therefore there is no scope around, everything is just a text and the preprocessor doesn't care about program units.

Therefore, 1., 2. and 3. all are valid from the place of their definition until the file end or until `#undef`. They are also valid in recursively `#include`d files.

If by guards you mean `#undef` then yes, otherwise a warning or error about redefinition appears, but only if you include all those files from a single file. If they are independent then no.

The key is to think about the preprocessor as a text replacement tool. It knows *nothing* about Fortran.

Last thing, the preprocessor is non-standard, but widely available.