# What does a C #include statement do in a Fortran code?

Tags: c, fortran, c-preprocessor

In the middle of a code there is a C language statement. I don't know why it is there and how the compiler does not give back an error. Is it for C binding? Does it mean that this module can be used by C program or vice versa?

```
USE LISTS
USE LINKEDLIST_ROUTINES

#include "macros.h"

IMPLICIT NONE

PRIVATE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a C language statement, but a C preprocessor (`cpp`) statement.

Any text file can use the preprocessor, even Fortran source codes, but you must call the preprocessor before compiling.

Many Fortran compilers will call the preprocessor for you with flags `-cpp` or `-fpp` or similar. They might also call it for you if the file suffix starts with capital `F`.

What the `#include "file"` does is the same as what it does in C source files, it inserts the text from the file in that location.

There is also a standard Fortran (90+) statement `include`. It is similar, but happens after any eventual pre-processing has been done, see [Includes revealing with Fortran preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498562/includes-revealing-with-fortran-preprocessor) for more.