# Error with hashtag include in Fortran 90 code

Tags: compilation, fortran, header-files, gfortran

Hello stack overflow (long time stalker, small time question asker),

I have inherited some ice sheet modelling code, which calls on the [LIS library](https://www.ssisc.org/lis/index.en.html). I have successfully installed LIS on my machine and I'm trying to write my own derivative of the modelling code.

In the original code LIS is called as `#include #lisf.h` where lisf.h appears to be a header file of some sort (first two code blocks below).

```
#ifndef __LISF_H__
#define __LISF_H__

#ifndef WIN32
#define SIZEOF_VOID_P 8
#else
#define SIZEOF_VOID_P 4
#endif
```

However, when I use `#include #lisf.h` in my own code as follows:

```
        type(yelmo_class)         :: model_input
        type(yiso_class)          :: elsa_layers

        #include "lisf.h"
        LIS_MATRIX               :: A_lis

        write(*,*) "bonjour"
```

I get the (somewhat expected, as # is not a standard character in Fortran) error:

```
   20 |         #include "lisf.h"
      |         1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616644/what-does-a-c-include-statement-do-in-a-fortran-code) it seems adding -cpp in the compilation line ought to do the trick, but alas it does not.

My current compilation code includes:

```
FC=gfortran #the compiler to use
lis=-I/usr/local/bin/include #location of the lis library header lisf.h
$FC -cpp elsa_classes.f90 elsa0.f90 -o elsa0 $NCf $lis $mpi
```

Thank you :)

--update--

As pointed out by Vladimir, Ben's question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953392/can-cpp-preprocessing-statement-in-fortran-be-indented) does have answers to this problem.

My understanding is that the C preprocessor (the -cpp flag in the compiler) requires the preprocessing statement to start at the beginning of the line. This explains why the original `#include #lisf.h` statement worked (no indentation) but mine did not (indented).

Comment: Please show a full [mcve]. How *exactly* does the offending line look like? Does it start in column 1 or in some other columns? Some preprocessors, like the `cpp` in `gfortran`, require the directives to start in the first column.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953392/can-cpp-preprocessing-statement-in-fortran-be-indented and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397793/fortran-2008-conditional-compilation?noredirect=1&lq=1 Probably a duplicate.

Comment: But it is still not clear to me why the error is "somewhat expected". If it is expected, what  do you not understand about it? If it is not a duplicate of what I linked, please show the exact code and I am happy to reopen the question ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for linking these answers. I use Fortran a reasonable amount but don't really use C day to day. I think this is worth being posted as a question because it involves #include not #define and someone who encounters one but no the other in their Fortran code may not immediately be aware that this is a C preprocessing issue.

Comment: The question is not going to be deleted. It will just point to the previous questions as a signpost https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416217/are-questions-closed-as-duplicates-eventually-deleted